# Reading and inserting part of a csv file using php - not wanting repeating data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Very novice student programmer here  :-) I want to read part of a CSV file and insert into phpMyadmin using sql insert statement.  I am a bit stuck... there is a column UN sub-region name and I only want each region to populate my database table once with its relevant regional score.

I have tried array_unique to print each region once however I also want to be able to get the corresponding score and be able insert both into a table in phpMyAdmin.
Here is my output: [image: runonceregion.php in browser].

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

```html
<?php

include("../connection/conn.php");
$file = "Global_Index_Data.csv";
$regionName =[];
$regionScore =[];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $filepath = fopen($file, "r");

    while (($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) != FALSE) {
        $region = $line[5];
        $score = $line[7];
    
        $regionName[] = $region;
        $regionScore[] = $score;
   }

  
    $resultName = array_unique($regionName);
     echo sizeof($resultName)."<br>";
      print_r($resultName);
      print_r($regionScore);

    
      //$regionNameScore = [$result, $line[7]];
      
      //print_r($regionNameScore);
    
}
 
?>
```

[image: datesetColsHighlighted]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a single *associative array* to pair and sum up a region's score across all rows provided by your CSV file:

```php
<?php
//...
$regionScoreByName = [];
while (($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== false) {
    $regionName = $line[5];
    $regionScore = $line[7];
    $currentRegionScore = $regionScoreByName[$regionName] ?? 0;
    $regionScoreByName[$regionName] = $currentRegionScore + $regionScore;
}

foreach($regionScoreByName as $regionName => $regionScore) {
    // Insert region score by region name into your database
}
```

*Edit: mind the CSV column headers when processing the region scores this way.*

**Edit 2: I seem to have misunderstand your desired result. Instead of summing up the region scores (as single insert statements), you seem to want to *group* the individual regional score records by their region name (and insert them individually).**

So instead of using an associative array to sum up a region's score, we can use it to *group* all region scores by their respective region name:

```php
<?php
//...
$regionScoresByName = [];
while (($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== false) {
    $regionName = $line[5];
    $regionScore = $line[7];
    if (false === isset($regionScoresByName[$regionName])) {
        $regionScoresByName[$regionName] = [];
    }
    $regionScoresByName[$regionName][] = $regionScore;
}

foreach($regionScoresByName as $regionName => $regionScores) {
    foreach($regionScores as $regionScore) {
        // Insert region score by region name into your database
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen thank you so much for taking time to reply :-) I tried the above but I am not getting the output I am expecting.  Can you tell me what "?? 0;" refers on the 8th line of your code am I suppose to change this to something else? If I run the code as is with a print_r statement its totaling the regional scores where as I only want to output the regional score as it is in the CSV file. So for example  "Southern Asia , 69.5"

Comment: The `??` operator is the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). A shorthand for checking if a variable or array element is set and assign a value accordingly. For example: `$a = $b['foo'] ?? 0` assigns `0` to `$a` if `$b['foo']` does not exist (and otherwise assigns the value of `$b['foo']` to `$a`).

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen van der Laan here is what I did. I wanted to print_r to check.

```html
<?php

include("../connection/conn.php");
$file = "Global_Index_Data.csv";
$regionName = [];
$regionScore = [];
$regionScoreByName = [];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $filepath = fopen($file, "r");

    $regionScoreByName = [];
    while (($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== false) {
        $regionName = $line[5];
        $regionScore = $line[7];
        $currentRegionScore = $regionScoreByName[$regionName] ?? 0;
        $regionScoreByName[$regionName] = $currentRegionScore+$regionScore;
    }
    
    print_r($regionScoreByName);
    foreach($regionScoreByName as $regionName => $regionScore) {
       
    }

}

?>
```

[image: output]

Comment: Consider editing your original post for this kind of supplementary info instead next time!